# JQUERY add dynamic form with id

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a form with 2 select form and 1 input form. Actually ,, there are inside a div 'table-form'.

I have a jquery script that add dynamic a table-form, but the field have same name. It's possible to add dynamic form with an id?

```
 <form id="form-container" method="GET">
          <div class="table-form">
            <div class="row" id="base-form">
              <div class="col">
                <select name="field" class="form-control">
                   {% for f in form %}
                    <option value="{{f.label}}">{{f.label}}</option>
                   {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <select name="lookup" class="form-control">
                    <option value="iexact">iexact</option>
                    <option value="icontains">icontains</option>
                    <option value="in">in</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <input id="value" class="form-control" type="text" name="value" placeholder="value..." value="{{ current_value }}">
              </div>
              <div class="col" id="col-delete">
                <button id="delete-form" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onClick="deleteForm();"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
          <button id="add-form" type="button" class="btn btn-form">Add form</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-form">Search</button>
          <button type="reset" name="btn-reset" class="btn btn-form" value="btn-reset">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var counter = 0
const html = $('div.table-form').first().html();
$('#add-form').on('click', function() {
  $('div.table-form').append(`${html}`);
});

function deleteForm() {
  $('#base-form').each(function(index, item){
    $(item).remove();
  })
}
</script>
```

I want something like this:

```
<div class="table-form">
                <div class="row" id="base-form">
                  <div class="col">
                    <select name="field1" class="form-control">
                       {% for f in form %}
                        <option value="{{f.label}}">{{f.label}}</option>
                       {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <select name="lookup1" class="form-control">
                        <option value="iexact">iexact</option>
                        <option value="icontains">icontains</option>
                        <option value="in">in</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <input id="value" class="form-control" type="text" name="value1" placeholder="value..." value="{{ current_value }}">
                  </div>
<div class="table-form">
                <div class="row" id="base-form">
                  <div class="col">
                    <select name="field2" class="form-control">
                       {% for f in form %}
                        <option value="{{f.label}}">{{f.label}}</option>
                       {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <select name="lookup2" class="form-control">
                        <option value="iexact">iexact</option>
                        <option value="icontains">icontains</option>
                        <option value="in">in</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                    <input id="value" class="form-control" type="text" name="value2" placeholder="value..." value="{{ current_value }}">
                  </div>
```

in order to construct a dict like:

```
field=State+text&lookup=iexact&value=toto%2Ctutu&field2=Name&lookup2=iexact&value2=titi
```

Comment: Suggestion : use array name attributes like `name="field[]",... for others`, so that once you post form you get the data in array format and index of it will tell you thet value is coming from first form or second form or third form..... Also it will be better to se POST instead of GET